# What is the difference between routine and process

Tags: operating-system

I am studying memory management in operating system and in general context i just want to know is there any difference between **routine** and **process**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is.

A *routine* usually means a piece of code such as a subroutine, coroutine or function that is called by other other code in some way.

A *process* is code that is actually in execution. This implies that one routine could actually be part of the codes being executed in two (or more) processes.